# Output list of integers divisible by Y and Z Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to write a function that would output a list of integers divisible by Y and Z from 1 to 500. However I get an empty list. What am I doing wrong?

```
divisByYnZ :: Int -> Int -> [Int]
divisByYnZ y z = [x | x <- [1..500], y `mod` 2 == 0 && z `mod` 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Why do you write ``y `mod` 2`` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A number `x` is divisible by a number `y`, in case `mod x y == 0`. If you want numbers to be divisible by `y`, you thus should rewrite you filter `` y `mod` 2 == 0 ``, to `` x `mod` y == 0 `` (here `x` is the number you want to filter after all), or more compact `mod x y == 0`.

So we can rewrite it to:

```
divisByYnZ y z = [x | x <- [1..500], mod x y == 0, mod x z == 0]
```

## Optimizing the generator

This is however not very efficient: imagine that `y` is `100`, then it means we will each time generate hundred elements, before one of the elements matches. We thus better first "prepare" the generator to only generate numbers that are divisible by `y`. Which is `[y, y+y..500]` (we here make the assumption that `y` is *strictly* positive):

```
-- given y is strictly positive
divisByYnZ y z = [x | x <- [y, y+y..500], mod x z == 0]
```

## Combining two modulo checks with the *least common multiple*

A number is divisibly by two numbers `a` and `b`, if and only if it is divisible by the *least common multiple* (LCM). In Haskell the prelude has a function [**`lcm :: Integral i => i -> i -> i`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lcm) that calculates the least common multiple. We can thus rewrite the list comprehension to:

```
-- given y and z are strictly positive
divisByYnZ y z = [t, t+t..500]
    where t = lcm y z
```